# Javascript detect if child of parent element has a class set

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="myclass"></div>   
</div>
```

How can I detect if inside of `main`div there is an element with `myclass` set?

PS. Vanilla JS, no jQuery

Answer (score 11):

The below code searches for any element with a class inside a parent using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
if (document.querySelectorAll("#main .myclass").length > 0) 
{
  console.log("#main has .myclass inside");
}
else 
{
  console.log("#main has no .myclass inside");
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="myclass"></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: After seeing this, I have just now realized that getting element functions in javascript can occur on any node, and now I sort of more understand how the "document" is a node, but so are each elements. Sort of just had an epiphany on how javascript works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
if(document.getElementById('main').getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0]) {
  alert('class found'); 
}else{
  alert('class not found'); 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="myclass"></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### classList

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One very nice solution is to use the classList Method `contains`. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

#### querySelector

But I would prefer `querySelector` because you can easily check if the querySelector finds an element. (If it doesn't, then querySelector returns null)

```js
function checkOne() {
  const check = document.querySelectorAll('#main > div');
  const res = [];
  check.forEach(e => {
    if (e.classList.contains('myclass') ) {
      res.push(true);
    }
  })
  return res.length > 0 ? true : false;  
}

function checkTwo() {
  const check = document.querySelector('#main .myclass');
  return check  ? true : false;
}

console.log("checkOne", checkOne());
console.log("checkTwo", checkTwo());
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="hello">1</div>   
  <div class="myclass">1</div>   
  <div class="world">1</div>   
</div>
```